# Access all request-scoped beans at runtime in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc

In my application I would like to propagate a value/message to multiple http clients. For that I have created an endpoint which returns a completable future of boolean type. For resolving this future I have created another endpoint which receives desired value. I want to use Spring's @RequestScope so I don't have to manage creating and destroying those instances by my own. However the following code won't work because I cannot retrieve all current request-scoped beans.

---

*Scenario*:

1. I call /future endpoint
2. I call /future endpoint again in different Postman tab
3. I call /complete endpoint with param value=true

*Expected result*:
Each /future call receives `true` value

*Actual result*:
Each /future call hangs till timeout w/o receiving any value

*Logs*:

```
Manager in /future: com.example.demo.FutureManager@12c048e7
Manager in /future: com.example.demo.FutureManager@38586896
{scopedTarget.futureManager=com.example.demo.FutureManager@209c5275, futureManager=com.example.demo.FutureManager@209c5275}
```

From the logs I can assume that indeed different instances of FutureManager were created for each endpoint call but upon /complete call there is only new, different instance available and those first two are gone? Or not seen by applicationContext?

---

**Controllers**

```
@RestController
class FutureController(
    private val manager: FutureManager
) {

    @GetMapping("/future")
    fun getFuture(): Boolean {
        println("Manager in /future: $manager")
        return manager.get()
    }
}

@RestController
class CompleteFutureController(
    private val applicationContext: WebApplicationContext
) {

    @GetMapping("/complete")
    fun getFuture(@RequestParam value: Boolean) {
        applicationContext.getBeansOfType(FutureManager::class.java)
            .also { println(it) }
            .values
            .forEach { it.complete(value) }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@RequestScope
class FutureManager {

    private val future = CompletableFuture<Boolean>()

    fun complete(value: Boolean) = future.complete(value)

    fun get(): Boolean = future.get()
}
```

Any help or explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: This wil not ever work. You cannot access request scoped beans from request x in request y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about accessing RequestScope beans directly using WebApplicationContext. There surely is workaround solution using bean lifecycle. My working example is:

```
@Service
class FutureService {
    val futureManagers = mutableListOf<FutureManager>()
}
```

Register/Unregister each FutureManager:

```
@Service
@RequestScope
class FutureManager(private val futureService: FutureService) : DisposableBean, InitializingBean {

    private val future = CompletableFuture<Boolean>()

    fun complete(value: Boolean) = future.complete(value)

    fun get(): Boolean = future.get()

    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        futureService.futureManagers.add(this)
    }
    
    override fun destroy() {
        futureService.futureManagers.remove(this)
    }
}
```

Complete them using:

```
@RestController
class CompleteFutureController(
    private val futureService: FutureService
) {
    @GetMapping("/complete")
    fun getFuture(@RequestParam value: Boolean) {
        futureService.futureManagers.forEach {
            println(it)
            it.complete(value)
        }
    }
}
```

While this is working, I don't think it is the best solution and suggestions are welcome.